# jQuery Sliding Effect not working

Tags: jquery, sliding

Hi i m trying to do a slide left & right effect on my Web-Page.
But it cannot seem to work it.
Pls can anybody correct it & work it.

instead of numbers there are images.

i have created a JS Fiddle for the same

http://goo.gl/kz3JX

Comment: Got any code? Examples? Anything?

Comment: Share the fiddle with us?

Comment: sorry : stackOverflow wasnt letting me insert JSFiddle.
So had to do it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download any jQuery slider and insert:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-slider.html